# ON_CANCEL never getting called

Tags: android, button, ontouchlistener

So im trying to make my button change its image, when i press down it changes correctly, when i lift up while on the button the ACTION_UP does get called... however, when ACTION_DOWN is called and i move my finger off (outside) the button and lift up, the ACTION_UP is still getting called. It should be setting the image back to normal and doing nothing else.

```
twitterBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent touchEvent) {
                switch(touchEvent.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        twitterBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logintwittertouched);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        twitterBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logintwitter);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        twitterBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logintwitter);
                        try {
                            adapter.authorize(MainActivity.this, Provider.TWITTER);
                            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Connecting to Twitter", true);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.v(getString(R.string.clickrerr), "" + e.toString());
                        }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in XML:

1. Create `res/drawable/twitter_button.xml`:

   ```
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_button_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_button_off"/>
   ```

   It uses 2 images: `twitter_button_on.png` and `twitter_button_off.png`, which you should      also place in the `drawable` folder.
2. In your layout, add this to your `<Button>`:

   ```
   android:background="@drawable/twitter_button"
   ```

Comment: Then resort back to my onClick method?

Comment: I don't understand your question very well, but yes, you can use for example `android:onClick="yourMethod"` in `<Button>`. Or `button.setOnClickListener()`. Maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) will also help you.

Comment: RIght... the reason i was using onTouch was because i couldn't achieve what your XML SAYS its going to accomplish, haven't tested, im replacing my setOnTouchListener back to setOnClickListener already. I'll accept once tested and working. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much easier then coding an onTouchListener. Thanks again.